# I'm a CS PhD student. I want to re-study some of college mathematics

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, education

I'm a PhD student in CS and I have a fair amount of background in mathematics. But it's been many years since I studied Mathematics in college. I would like to refresh and in many cases, understand the topics more intuitively, so that I could make pictures of the equations in my head when I see them. I already read suggestions including the Princeton Companion to Mathematics, but I think I'm looking for something different. I read many papers that include some mathematical material and when I do not understand something very clearly, I would like to go back and study that topic for some hours (or a couple of days). Do you know of some book/website/material like this?

Examples of things I liked in the past are some material in betterexplained.com, this piece on matrix ([Understanding matrices intuitively](http://blog.stata.com/2011/03/09/understanding-matrices-intuitively-part-2/)), and this AMS feature on SVD ([We Recommend a Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-svd)).

**Edit:** fair amount of background in Mathematics means: someone who does not need to start from the very basic, or need resources that are without formulas and numbers; has the amount of background a typical graduate student in a scientific field like Computer Science has, but not as much as someone in Theoretical CS has.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "fair amount of background in mathematics". Are you comfortable with Algebra at the level of Herstein or Dummit? In my opinion every Science grad need to read math, since, Math makes you to think in right way.

Comment: You are most likely to enjoy mathematical logic. You could look up Mendelson's book. Or you might enjoy some algebra (linear algebra/group theory) for which I would recommend Herstein's book.

Comment: tried to explain "fair amount of background in mathematics" above- I know the importance of Math and how it makes one think and that's one of the reasons for this question. I'd much rather appreciate more constructive comments and suggestions than nitpicking on the details.


@PrahladVaidyanathan, thanks.

Comment: I recommend Gilbert Strang's books Linear Algebra and its Applications, Introduction to Applied Math, and Computational Science and Engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try looking at "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. The aim of the book is to give a survey of some of the topics relevant to CS (in a concrete manner and in a form useful to practitioners). Just a thought.